# accessing a json child object not in an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to accessing a json child object which is not in an array. i've tried accessing it with my below script but its not working. i want to be able to access the menuCategory Object

JSON

```
 [
  {
    "id": 67,
    "name": "Wednesday Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-06-12 00:00:00",
    "expiryDate": "2019-06-12 16:11:00",
    "status": "APPROVED",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 45,
        "name": "Waakye, Gari and Wele",
        "description": "A very well designed food for all kids",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "LUNCH",
        "unitPrice": 30,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 46,
        "name": "Gari and Beans",
        "description": "A very well designed food for all kidsss",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "LUNCH",
        "unitPrice": 12,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ],
    "menuCategory": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "hello"
    }
  }
]
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
callEditMenu(parent, content) {
  this.modalService.open(content);
  this.editMenuCategoryId = parent.menuCategory.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be like

```js
const parent = [{"id":67,"name":"Wednesday Menu","serveDate":"2019-06-12 00:00:00","expiryDate":"2019-06-12 16:11:00","status":"APPROVED","isEnabled":true,"meals":[{"id":45,"name":"Waakye, Gari and Wele","description":"A very well designed food for all kids","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":30,"status":"ENABLED"},{"id":46,"name":"Gari and Beans","description":"A very well designed food for all kidsss","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":12,"status":"ENABLED"}],"menuCategory":{"id":2,"name":"hello"}}]

console.log(parent[0].menuCategory.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent argument in the callEditMenu function is referring to the JSON you included then try `parent[0].menuCategory.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [{"id":67,"name":"Wednesday Menu","serveDate":"2019-06-12 00:00:00","expiryDate":"2019-06-12 16:11:00","status":"APPROVED","isEnabled":true,"meals":[{"id":45,"name":"Waakye, Gari and Wele","description":"A very well designed food for all kids","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":30,"status":"ENABLED"},{"id":46,"name":"Gari and Beans","description":"A very well designed food for all kidsss","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":12,"status":"ENABLED"}],"menuCategory":{"id":2,"name":"hello"}}]

for (let item of arr)  {
  if (item.hasOwnProperty("menuCategory")) {
    console.log(item["menuCategory"]);
  }
};

let res = arr.filter((item) => item && item.menuCategory);
console.log(res[0].menuCategory);
```

In case you need to find it dynamically. Above are two different ways

Answer (score 0):

Considering there would be multiple items in your array of objects, you can iterate through each object to get the menuCategory name as

```js
let obj = [
  {
    "id": 67,
    "name": "Wednesday Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-06-12 00:00:00",
    "expiryDate": "2019-06-12 16:11:00",
    "status": "APPROVED",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 45,
        "name": "Waakye, Gari and Wele",
        "description": "A very well designed food for all kids",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "LUNCH",
        "unitPrice": 30,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 46,
        "name": "Gari and Beans",
        "description": "A very well designed food for all kidsss",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "LUNCH",
        "unitPrice": 12,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ],
    "menuCategory": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "hello"
    }
  }
];

obj.forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem.menuCategory.name);
});
```